# Jenkins job fails with error set -o pipefail

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job written in Linux to trigger my automation scripts.
I have below command to navigate to the file I intend to trigger:

```
sh "set -o pipefail && pwd && cd base/path && suite=${features}"
```

This executes as below:
set -o pipefail
base/script.sh: 1: set Illegal option -o pipefail

The log is not much useful. How can I identify what exactly is causing error?

Comment: set in sh is different from the bash built-in, see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/set.1p.html

Comment: `set` is basically the same, but `pipefail` is not a standard option defined by POSIX; it's specific to `bash`. You probably aren't using `bash`, but some other shell like `dash`, as the POSIX shell.

Comment: Thanks I went through the link but could not get much. I am still not able to get what could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
 sh label: "Text" , script: """
        #!/bin/bash
        set -eo pipefail

        command
 """
```